# Cannot save removed items from list to core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm fairly new to Swift and have an issue that I have not found an answer to on stack overflow.  I'm sure I'm missing something stupid but cant figure it out.  Help is appreciated.

I'm working on an app that allows the user to click on a button and add items to an array and click on another button and remove an item from the array.  The array is being saved to core data.  By clicking on the buttons I can successfully add and delete items to/from the array.  When adding items to the array, I can also successfully save it to core data.  The issue arises when I try and remove an item from the array.  I use the `context.save()` but nothing saves.  I believe this is because the `viewContext` does not record any changes.  How do I force that?  Note, this does not generate any errors in the catch blocks.

Here's the relevant code for the `ViewController` class

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let itemContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentItemContainer.viewContext
var savedItems = [Item]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    do {
        savedItems = try itemContext.fetch(Item.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved Error: 10003 \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
}

@IBAction func removeLastItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
    savedItems.remove(at: savedItems.count-1)
    appDelegate.saveItemContext()
}
```

Here's the relevant code for the `AppDelegate` class

```
lazy var persistentItemContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let itemContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "BlindedByTheLight")
    itemContainer.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {
        (storeDescription, error) in
        print(storeDescription)
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved Error: 10001 \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return itemContainer
}()


func saveItemContext(){
    let itemContext = persistentItemContainer.viewContext
    if itemContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try itemContext.save()
        }
        catch {
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved Error: 10002 \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need delete object in your context:

```
let itemToDelete = savedItems[savedItems.count-1]
savedItems.remove(at: savedItems.count-1)
appDelegate.persistentItemContainer.viewContext.delete(itemToDelete)
appDelegate.saveItemContext()
```